# ACF repeater field on Custom post type taxonomy returns errors (Timber theme)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I have created a custom post type and its taxonomy. I also have ACF repeater image field to the taxonomy, but every time when I add image to the field, there are errors like this.

```
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-tax-query.php on line 558
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 933

Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given 
in /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1597

Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given 
in /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 2207
```

This is the query in php:

```
$terms = new Timber\Term();


$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'apartments',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'apartment_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $terms,
        )
    )
);


$tax_apartments = new Timber\PostQuery($args);

$context['tax_apartments'] = $tax_apartments;
$context['apartment_name'] = $terms->name;
$context['apartment_image'] = $terms->apartment_image;
```

This is the var_dump of $terms

```
object(Timber\Term)#7418 (20) {
  ["PostClass"]=>
  string(11) "Timber\Post"
  ["TermClass"]=>
  string(4) "Term"
  ["object_type"]=>
  string(4) "term"
  ["_children"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "A-apartment"
  ["taxonomy"]=>
  string(18) "apartment_category"
  ["id"]=>
  int(12)
  ["ID"]=>
  int(12)
  ["term_id"]=>
  int(12)
  ["slug"]=>
  string(6) "a-apartment"
  ["term_group"]=>
  int(0)
  ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
  int(12)
  ["parent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["count"]=>
  int(7)
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
  ["term_order"]=>
  string(1) "0"  
  ["apartment_image"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["building_image"]=>
      string(58) "http://localhost/content/uploads/2019/05/subpage-lift2.jpg"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["building_image"]=>
  string(57) "http://localhost/content/uploads/2019/05/subpage-lift.jpg"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["building_image"]=>
      string(51) "http://localhost/content/uploads/2019/05/square.png"
    }
  }
}
```

This is in twig:

```
{% for photo in apartment_image %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <img src="{{photo['building_image']}}" alt="">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is acf for custom post type taxonomy

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_local_field_group') ):

acf_add_local_field_group(array(
'key' => 'group_5cfa36fe90c69',
'title' => 'Apartment info',
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'field_5cfa3a1c52062',
        'label' => 'Images',
        'name' => 'apartment_image',
        'type' => 'repeater',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required' => 0,
        'conditional_logic' => 0,
        'wrapper' => array(
            'width' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'id' => '',
        ),
        'collapsed' => '',
        'min' => 0,
        'max' => 0,
        'layout' => 'table',
        'button_label' => '',
        'sub_fields' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'field_5cfa3a4d52063',
                'label' => 'Buiding Image',
                'name' => 'building_image',
                'type' => 'image',
                'instructions' => '',
                'required' => 0,
                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                'wrapper' => array(
                    'width' => '',
                    'class' => '',
                    'id' => '',
                ),
                'return_format' => 'url',
                'preview_size' => 'thumbnail',
                'library' => 'all',
                'min_width' => '',
                'min_height' => '',
                'min_size' => '',
                'max_width' => '',
                'max_height' => '',
                'max_size' => '',
                'mime_types' => '',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'location' => array(
    array(
        array(
            'param' => 'taxonomy',
            'operator' => '==',
            'value' => 'apartment_category',
        ),
    ),
),
'menu_order' => 0,
'position' => 'normal',
'style' => 'default',
'label_placement' => 'top',
'instruction_placement' => 'label',
'hide_on_screen' => '',
'active' => true,
'description' => '',
));

endif;
```

If i remove images from the field, errors are gone. I haven't figured out yet for a solution. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You can check the link - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84061/php-warning-preg-match-expects-php-warning-strip-tags

Comment: Can you put you code in the question

Comment: Just updated my code in the question

Comment: Since the errors come from the taxonomy related includes, and the first one specifically from the one handling tax queries, my guess would be that it doesn’t like what you are passing in with `'terms' => $terms,`. That should be a string or an array of strings here, but you are passing whatever the result of `new Timber\Term();` is. Since you are using `$context['apartment_name'] = $terms->name;` later on, that value is probably also what you should be passing for `terms` in the query in the first place?

Comment: I also added var_dump of $term, can you have look?

Comment: I removed $context["terms"] = $term; as it was my test and the errors are still the same.